# Post method that calls another one for returning the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, post-redirect-get

In an MVC4 project I need to "refresh" the page depending on some messages that can be present, otherwise I just redirect to a page, and if presenting again the page if them messages are present I would like to avoid just returning the View as it will cause then the double submission when the user tries to refresh it.

What I'm trying to do is this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SampleMethod()
{
    viewModel = _builder.Build();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public void SampleMethod(SampleViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var response = serviceCall;
        var errorMessages = response.ErrorMessages;

        if (!errorMessages.Any())
        {
            //Redirect to proper view
        }
        else
            vm = _builder.Build();
    }

    else vm = _builder.Build(); //There is some validation error I rebuild

    CashbackOffersConfirmation(vm);
}

public ActionResult SampleMethodConfirmation(SampleViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View("SampleMethod", viewModel);
}
```

It goes through the process
 but the final page is .../SampleMethod instead of .../SampleMethodConfirmation and is blank,

Is this something to do with the routing (quite lost in this)? Is this a correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: Are you returning the correct view? You're returning return View("SampleMethod", viewModel); and perhaps it needs to be return View("SampleMethodConfirmation", viewModel);?

Comment: you might try return RedirectToAction("SampleMethod") instead of return view

Comment: Problem if I return RedirecToAction is that I lose the state of the view. And if I return SampleMethodConfirmation I would need to basically duplicate the view code existing in the SampleMethod one (althoug maybe using a partial one it will work)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the object model from the view to the controller, you need to make a post request. Make sure you use a form that will generate the post request.
Also make the SampleMethodConfirmation method a post.

E.g.: add [HttpPost] on top of the method in the controller